# Making a game like snake but it doesn't get longer, and when I use my detection method, it always reads the fruit and player pos as 0 so it goes off

Tags: python, python-turtle

The code is supposed to detect the player and fruit location, then see if they are close enough, it shoud complete the command. But when I run the program, it only detects the distance between the player and fruit as 0 every time.

```
#---imports---
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
#---making the turtles---
player = trtl.Turtle()
fruits = trtl.Turtle()
wn = trtl.Screen()
player.shape("classic")
#---variables---
fruit = ["circle", "square", "triangle", "arrow", "circle", "square", "triangle", "arrow"]
colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
score = -1

#---game commands---
def move():
  player.penup()
  player.forward(5)
  print(abs(player.ycor()-fruits.ycor()))
  
def turn_up():
  player.setheading(90)

def turn_right():
  player.setheading(0)

def turn_left():
  player.setheading(180)

def turn_down():
  player.setheading(270)

def spawn():
  new_ycor=rand.randint(-150, 150)             
  new_xcor=rand.randint(-150, 150)
  fruits.penup()
  fruits.setpos(new_xcor,new_ycor)
  fruits.shape(rand.choice(fruit))
  fruits.color(rand.choice(colors))

def collision():
  xDist = abs(player.xcor()-fruits.xcor())
  yDist = abs(player.ycor()-fruits.ycor())
  if xDist < 10 and yDist < 10:
    spawn()
    print("Collision!")
#---game events---
collision()
wn.onkeypress(turn_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(turn_right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(turn_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(turn_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(move, "space")
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()'
```

The spawn() command should make the fruit spawn at a different place everytime it runs. And the collision() command should detect the location of the fruit and player, then subtract them to see if they are too close. But it only detects the distance as 0 no matter what I do.

```
def spawn():
  new_ycor=rand.randint(-150, 150)             
  new_xcor=rand.randint(-150, 150)
  fruits.penup()
  fruits.setpos(new_xcor,new_ycor)
  fruits.shape(rand.choice(fruit))
  fruits.color(rand.choice(colors))
def collision():
  xDist = abs(player.xcor()-fruits.xcor())
  yDist = abs(player.ycor()-fruits.ycor())
  if xDist < 10 and yDist < 10:
    spawn()
    print("Collision!")
```

Comment: You only call `collision()` *once*, as your program is starting up, and at that point in time both the player and fruit are at the same, default location - so their distance actually IS zero.  You need to call `spawn()` instead during startup, and call `collision()` repeatedly - from within `move()`, perhaps.

Comment: thank you! I'll make sure tho try that

Comment: Please could you create a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), instead of pasting in all your code? It would be so much easier to read.